# Generate magento xml feed for Google shopping

Tags: xml, magento, google-shopping

I need to integrate my ecommerce with google shopping, but for that I need magento generate a xml feed of products to upload in google shopping, I only found payd modules and in the moment we cant spend with modules, someone have some suggestion about other way to generate this xml feed of products? thanks !

Comment: please let me know if you have found any free module.